# Подсчет суммы чисел

Tags: php

Составить программу, которая выводит на экран в столбик 20 целых случайных чисел из диапазона -20 до 80 и подсчитывает количество отрицательных чисел и их сумму и количество положительных чисел и их сумму и выводит эти данные на экран.

Сделал первую часть, а с подсчетом не получается.

```
<?php
//начальное значение суммы чётных чисел
$sum_even_numbers = 0;
//начальное значение суммы нечётных чисел
$sum_odd_numbers = 0;
//количество чётных чисел
$count_even_numbers = 0;
//количество нечётных чисел
$count_odd_numbers = 0;
for ($i=1; $i<=20; $i++) {
$number[$i] = rand(-20,80);
    echo "<br> $number[$i]";
   if ($number[$i]<0)

   else
?>
```

Comment: И в чем же проблема? Вы не знаете как сложение двух чисел в PHP сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если говорим про четность, то:

```
<?php
$sum_even_numbers = 0;
$sum_odd_numbers = 0;
$count_even_numbers = 0;
$count_odd_numbers = 0;
for ($i=1; $i<=20; $i++) {
  $number[$i] = rand(-20,80);
  echo "<br> $number[$i]";
  if ($number[$i]%2 = 0){
    $count_even_numbers++;
    $sum_even_numbers += $number[$i];
  }
  else{
    $count_odd_numbers++;
    $sum_odd_numbers += $number[$i];
  }
}
?>
```

Если говорим о положительных и отрицательных, то:

```
<?php
$sum_minus = 0;
$sum_plus = 0;
$count_minus = 0;
$count_plus = 0;
for ($i=1; $i<=20; $i++) {
  $number[$i] = rand(-20,80);
  echo "<br> $number[$i]";
  if ($number[$i]< 0){
    $count_minus++;
    $sum_minus += $number[$i];
  }
  else{
    $count_plus++;
    $sum_plus += $number[$i];
  }
}
?>
```